# Nokogiri search for word content controls

Tags: ruby, xml, ms-word, nokogiri

I want to find all Microsoft Word content control nodes in a document.xml. Because I am going to preprocess these controls, I need to find these guys recursively from a given xml node, BUT I want to stop at the first occurence.

Sample data : (The content control node is the `<w:sdt>` one)

*Assume these are the nodes I can see from a node X :*

```
<w:tc>
  <w:tcPr>
  ...
  </w:tcPr>
  <!-- A content control node I want to get -->
  <w:sdt>
    <w:sdtPr>
    ...
    </w:sdtPr>
    <w:sdtEndPr/>
    <w:sdtContent>
      ...
      <!--- Embedded in a content control. I don't want it now --->
      <w:sdt> 
        ...
      </w:sdt>
    </w:sdtContent>
  </w:sdt>
  ...
  <!-- Another content control ! It isn't embedded in a <w:sdt>, so I want this one -->
  <w:sdt>
  </w:sdt>
</w:tc>
...
<!--- Another one ! Not at the same depth, but not embedded so I want it ! -->
<w:sdt>
...
</w:sdt>
```

I want 3 out of the 4 nodes given above. If I just do a `nodeX.search('.//sdt')`, I will grab all 4 right ? How can I exclude the embedded one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just consider all the `sdt` nodes and keep looking its parents till

- You find node X, which means the content control isn't embedded (keep this node)
- You find a `sdt` ancestor

Code :

```
def find_nested_content_controls(node_set, cc_parent)
    nested_ccs = Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet.new(cc_parent.document)
    node_set.search('w|sdt').each do |cc|
        # Look at the parent node till we hit either the cc_parent, or another content_control
        current_node = cc
        loop do
            if current_node.parent == cc_parent 
                # It's not 2-level nested !
                nested_ccs.push(cc)
                break
            elsif /^sdt$/.match(current_node.parent.name)
                # It's >= 2-level nested, discard
                break
            elsif current_node == cc_parent.document.root
                raise 'Exception'
            end
            current_node = current_node.parent
        end
    end
    nested_ccs
end
```

Note : can be called with `document.root` as both parameters, to find the first level of Content Controls in the whole document